# Parallel loading of Input Files in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda

I have a Requirement, where I have three Input files and need to load them inside the Pandas Data Frame, before merging two of the files into one single Data Frame.

The File extension always changes, it could be .txt one time and .xlsx or .csv another time.

How Can I run this process parallel, in order to save the waiting/ loading time ?

This is my code at the moment,

```
from time import time # to measure the time taken to run the code
start_time = time()

Primary_File = "//ServerA/Testing Folder File Open/Report.xlsx"
Secondary_File_1 = "//ServerA/Testing Folder File Open/Report2.csv"
Secondary_File_2 = "//ServerA/Testing Folder File Open/Report2.csv"

import pandas as pd # to work with the data frames
Primary_df = pd.read_excel (Primary_File)
Secondary_1_df = pd.read_csv (Secondary_File_1)
Secondary_2_df = pd.read_csv (Secondary_File_2)

Secondary_df = Secondary_1_df.merge(Secondary_2_df, how='inner', on=['ID'])
end_time = time()

print(end_time - start_time)
```

It takes around 20 minutes for me to load my primary_df and secondary_df. So, I am looking for an efficient solution possibly using parallel processing to save time.
I timed by Reading operation and it takes most of the time approximately 18 minutes 45 seconds.

**Hardware Config :- Intel i5 Processor, 16 GB Ram and 64-bit OS**

> Question Made Eligible for bounty :- As I am looking for a working
>   code with detailed steps - using a **package with in anaconda
>   environment** that supports loading my input files Parallel and
>   storing them in a pandas data frame separately. This should eventually
>   save time.

Comment: You have at least 3 options; asyncio, Threads, Multi-process but I'm not sure if those options will give you enough performance. You need to see if reading operation take most of the time(in this case the above options should help you) or if creating the data-frames in memory take most of time.

Comment: Consider using dask (http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/why.html) as a substitute for pandas.

Comment: What kind of hardware do you have? I am not sure how you can get around this issue if the bottleneck is disk I/O.

Comment: @Logan Yes, Intel i5 Processor, 16 GB Ram and 64-bit OS.

Comment: You are IO bound and there is no getting around it.  The load time is the load time.

Comment: does it have to be read _directly_ into pandas?

Comment: No, it can be loaded into a different df and then moved into pandas

Comment: Short response is you will not get a meaningful speedup with this unless it really takes a TON of work to read in the original sources. See the GIL and pickling.

Comment: how big are these files? as bytes on disk, and number rows/columns?  what data types are the columns?  are they going to be given to you with rows sorted/ordered?

Comment: Try to import the files to a database first using database utility to import files. Then use pandas to import data from database. db import utilities might be faster compared to python.

Comment: Check [this](https://www.kaggle.com/gvyshnya/parallel-operations-over-a-pandas-df) snippet on Kaggle

Comment: You haven't provided enough information. Giving how long the entire code takes to run is insufficient, you need to describe how long each line of code takes. Otherwise, nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: What are the sizes of the files you read? You may have problems with fitting data in the memory, so a lot of memory swapping tales place, and not the I/O itself.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
from time import time 
import pandas as pd
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool


start_time = time()

pool = ThreadPool(processes=3)

Primary_File = "//ServerA/Testing Folder File Open/Report.xlsx"
Secondary_File_1 = "//ServerA/Testing Folder File Open/Report2.csv"
Secondary_File_2 = "//ServerA/Testing Folder File Open/Report2.csv"


# Define a function for the thread
def import_xlsx(file_name):
    df_xlsx = pd.read_excel(file_name)
    # print(df_xlsx.head())
    return df_xlsx


def import_csv(file_name):
    df_csv = pd.read_csv(file_name)
    # print(df_csv.head())
    return df_csv

# Create two threads as follows

Primary_df = pool.apply_async(import_xlsx, (Primary_File, )).get() 
Secondary_1_df = pool.apply_async(import_csv, (Secondary_File_1, )).get() 
Secondary_2_df = pool.apply_async(import_csv, (Secondary_File_2, )).get() 

Secondary_df = Secondary_1_df.merge(Secondary_2_df, how='inner', on=['ID'])
end_time = time()
```

Comment: I Imported _thread as thread. It is giving me an error on this code :- thread.start_new_thread(import_xlsx, [Primary_File]) and it says, the 2nd argument must be a tuple..

Comment: Ok, try now. Second arg is a tuple now.

Comment: Now, it gives me this error - import_xlsx() missing 1 required positional argument: 'file_name'

Comment: This is giving me a problem. The dataframe Primary_df, Secondary_1_df, Secondary_2_df are all returning a single integer value and not a dataframe with all columns and corresponding column values.

Comment: @Sid29 yeap, now it's return DataFrame, it works at 3 separate thread. Each of them is importing dataframe.

Comment: It works but saves no time at all. Saves 4-5 seconds for me.

Comment: Marking this as an answer, even when it didn't solve the problem (I/O constrains) it still gives me a clear idea of ThreadPooling and the code speaks.

Comment: Given that Pandas is advertised as NOT thread-safe, I'd be worried about using a threadpool. Curious, when you ran this, were multiple processes created ?

Answer (score 2):

Why not use `asyncio` over `multiprocessing`?

Instead of using multiple threads, you might want to first leverage on the I/O level with [an Async CSV Dict Reader](https://github.com/mosquito/aiofile#async-csv-dict-reader) (which can be parallelized using `multiprocessing` for multiple files). Afterwards, you can either concat the dicts and then load these dictionaries into pandas or load the individual dicts into pandas and concat there. 
However, pandas does not support `asyncio` so you will have a performance loss at some point.

Answer (score 1):

Try using @Cezary.Sz code but using (delete the calls to `.get()`), instead:

```
Primary_df_job = pool.apply_async(import_xlsx, (Primary_File, ))
Secondary_1_df_job = pool.apply_async(import_csv, (Secondary_File_1, ))
Secondary_2_df_job = pool.apply_async(import_csv, (Secondary_File_2, ))
```

Then

```
Secondary_1_df = Secondary_1_df_job.get()
Secondary_2_df = Secondary_2_df_job.get()
```

And you can use the dataframes, while `Primary_df_job` is loading.

```
Secondary_df = Secondary_1_df.merge(Secondary_2_df, how='inner', on=['ID'])
```

When you need `Primary_df` in your code, use

```
Primary_df = Primary_df_job.get()
```

This will block the execution until `Primary_df_job` is finished.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, due to **GIL (Global Interpreter Lock)** in Python, multiple threads do not run simultaneously — **all threads use the same single CPU's core**. That means if you create several threads to load your files, the total time will be equal (or actually greater) the time needed to load that files one-by-one.

More about GIL: https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock

To speed up load time you can try to switch from csv/excel to pickle files (or HDF).

Comment: Multiprocessing gets around the GIL, so this is an invalid objection.

Comment: I said multithreading, not multiprocessing. For multiprocessing you need to transfer a huge amount of data between processes which is memory consuming.

Comment: For for I/O intensive tasks GIL is less problematic. It is blocking for CPU-intensive tasks.

Answer (score 0):

You give the hardware details but you do not give the most interesting part: the number of disks you have, the type of RAID you have and the filesystem you are reading from.

If you only have one disk, no RAID, and a regular filesystem (ext4, XFS, etc.), like you mostly have on laptops, you will not be able to increase the bandwidth simply by throwing CPUs (multithread or multiprocess) at the problem. Using multiple threads, or asynchronous I/Os will help mask the latency a bit, but will not increase the bandwidth, because chances are you are already saturating it with a single reader process.

So using the code suggested by @Cezary.Sz, try moving one of the file to a USB3.0 external storage, or to SDSX storage. If you are running on a large workstation, look at the hardware details to see if several disks are available, and if you run on a large cluster, look for a parallel filesystem (BeeGFS, Lustre, etc.)