# Parallelized loading of data into Pandas Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to compare data from 2 azure databases, that each contain fair amount of data. Given that the sql query is i/o bound, I am wondering if I could kick off 2 queries (one to each database) concurrently, and have the returned data deposited into the respective 2 dataframes.

I have read that Pandas is not thread-safe (this is really unfortunate) otherwise the Python ThreadPoolExecutor along with Pandas pd.read_sql could handle it. Now a few questions:

1. is it still true that Pandas is still not threadsafe ?
2. is there a better library to use that is thread-safe ?
3. other thought on how to safely improve the performance of getting data into dataframes on my PC ? (using python)

Comment: hi yes perhaps that might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54309599/parallel-loading-of-input-files-in-pandas-dataframe

Comment: Walter does that answer your question?

Comment: @jspcal I will take a closer look and let you know. I

Comment: @Walter is it a dupe? :)

Comment: `is it still true that Pandas is still not threadsafe ?` It's true for a single dataframe. However, two threads can operate on two different dataframes in a thread-safe manner.

Comment: @NickODell that would be great news. I have been looking for documentation that more thoroughly explains Pandas thread safety issue(s), but have not found anything definitive. Do you have a pointer ?

Comment: Best resource I can point to is https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/gotchas.html#thread-safety Other than that, you could switch from multithreading to multiprocessing, which has no thread safety issues due to greater isolation.

Comment: @nickODell the multiprocessing may add a some time getting the data back into the same process memory. Thanks for the link, I will take a look.

Comment: Yes, that's a downside. It still may be faster than loading the data from the remote source.