# Faster alternatives to for loop and concatenate in python

Tags: python, performance, for-loop, concatenation

I am writing a python script where I am reading over 100s of data files, and then process the data using some equations and eventually, I would like to collect all the data into a single dataframe.

Currently, I use a for loop to go through each file at a time, import the data, then apply an equation on to the data, and then concatenate the data to an empty dataframe, which grows over time as more and more files are read. This method take a lot of time and I was wondering if there are faster alternatives.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions! :-)

Rifat

Comment: Are you using threading or multiprocessing yet? https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54309599/parallel-loading-of-input-files-in-pandas-dataframe
Potential duplicate?

Comment: Please share what you have already tried, what does "a lot of time" mean, what is acceptable to you? Further, are you using and planning to use only pandas or are you open to use other frameworks, languages etc as well. Adding these clarifications will help you get better answers quicker :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a 2 scan approach. In the first you access to all files and do only the data extraction. The outcome can be a single csv files or one json for each file. This step can be parallelized easily with  [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) library or [joblib](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

In the second scan you read and apply the computation, in this case you can benefit of vectorial computation if the data are loaded in a [pandas dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html).

The benefit of this approach is that data extraction will be done only when input files changes, if changes a subset of files, you will refresh only the extracted data related to them.
If you change something in the computation this can be repeated only using the extracted data and will go fast.